# AVPlayer on top of UIView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avkit

I'm new to using AVKit and was wondering if it was possible to mask a player onto a UIView. So the frame of the video is the frame of the cell.

If so where / how would I implement this.

Additionally,

If you know of any AVKit quick start guides or tutorials that'd be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, basically all you have to do is call `self.view.addSubview(AVPlayerLayer)`, and this is a layer for the APPlayer; after you instantiate the cell view, then make sure that `AVPlayer.frame = view.bounds`

Comment: I think it should be self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer) and frame should be set on playerLayer because AVPlayer is not a UIView and does not have a .frame property.